# CFExecute not executing appcmd.exe

Tags: iis-7, coldfusion-9, appcmd, cfexecute

I created the following code on a Cofdfusion server: file name: testWebsite.cfm

```
<cfoutput>
<cfset exec_command = "add site /name:""demosite"" /bindings:http://demosite.testserver.com:80 /physicalpath:""D:\Websites\demosite"" ">

<cfexecute name="C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe" arguments="#exec_command#" timeout="60" />

Done!
</cfoutput>
```

But when I execute this file e.g. http://www.demoserver.com/testcases/testWebsite.cfm

It just displays "Done!" without any errors, it doesn't execute the **add site** code.

Upon referring numerous documents, I checked the user rights under which both execute.
The **coldfusion service** is running as a domain user called **Webserver@domain.com**
I don't know how to check the same for IIS. 
So I checked the **World Wide Publishing Service** and **IIS Admin Service** - running as **Local System**.

Even if I log in as the administrator, I cannot add the **webserver user** to the **inetsrv** folder or the **appcmd.exe** located at C:\Windows\System32

Please help with any ideas/suggestions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If appcmd.exe is called from cmd.exe it should work:

```
<cfset vcCmdPath = "C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe">
<cfset vcAppCmdArg = "/c C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe">
<cfset exec_command = "add site /name:""demosite"" /bindings:http://demosite.testserver.com:80 /physicalpath:""D:\Websites\demosite"" ">

<cfexecute name="#vcCmdPath#" arguments="#vcAppCmdArg# #exec_command#" variable="vcAppCmdResults" timeout="60"></cfexecute>

<cfoutput>#vcAppCmdResults#</cfoutput>
```

I prefer to use variables for cmd.exe and appcmd.exe.